# How to generate log of sql script running from batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sql-delete, logfile

I have below delete_import.bat file which runs fine and it has following contents:

```
sqlplus @C:\Exp_Imp_Util\delete_tmc.sql
```

The deletetmc.sql file contents all the database objects which i want to delete. But now whenever i run the batch file it should create log of all delete statements and also it should write into log file if any oracle error occured while deleting the sql statements.

```
CONNECT TMC/TMC;
spool off
declare
stringa varchar2(100);

cursor cur is
select *
from user_objects;

begin
for c in cur loop
begin
stringa := '';

if c.object_type = 'VIEW' then

stringa := 'drop view ' || c.object_name;
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 

elsif c.object_type = 'TABLE' then

stringa := 'drop table ' || c.object_name || ' cascade constraints'; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 

elsif c.object_type = 'SEQUENCE' then

stringa := 'drop sequence ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 
elsif c.object_type = 'PACKAGE' then

stringa := 'drop package ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa;      

elsif c.object_type = 'TRIGGER' then

stringa := 'drop trigger ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa;      

elsif c.object_type = 'PROCEDURE' then

stringa := 'drop procedure ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 

elsif c.object_type = 'FUNCTION' then

stringa := 'drop function ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa;      
elsif c.object_type = 'SYNONYM' then

stringa := 'drop synonym ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 
elsif c.object_type = 'INDEX' then

stringa := 'drop index ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa; 
elsif c.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY' then

stringa := 'drop PACKAGE BODY ' || c.object_name; 
EXECUTE immediate stringa;      

end if;

     exception
when others then
null;
end; 
end loop;
-- PURGE recyclebin

end;
/
EXIT;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `SPOOL` to write to a file and then use `DBMS_OUTPUT`:

**script.sql**:

```
spool spool.txt
set serveroutput on
declare
    vSQL varchar2(1000);
begin
    vSQL := 'create table tab1 ( a number)';
    begin
        execute immediate vSQL;
        dbms_output.put_line('OK - ' || vSQL);
    exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('KO - ' || vSQL || ' - ' || sqlerrm);        
    end;

    vSQL := 'drop table tab1';
    begin
        execute immediate vSQL;
        dbms_output.put_line('OK - ' || vSQL);
    exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('KO - ' || vSQL || ' - ' || sqlerrm);        
    end;

    vSQL := 'drop table tab1';
    begin
        execute immediate vSQL;
        dbms_output.put_line('OK - ' || vSQL);
    exception
    when others then
        dbms_output.put_line('KO - ' || vSQL || ' - ' || sqlerrm);        
    end;
end;
/   
spool off
```

After running the script, the file **spool.txt** will be:

```
OK - create table tab1 ( a number)                                              
OK - drop table tab1                                                            
KO - drop table tab1 - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist                  

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: i tried it but in log file its showing as Connected. For testing i have create one table and tried to drop it from uing this batch file. The table got dropped but in log file its writing as Connected. No information about which table got dropped.

Comment: Maybe you have the CONN in the wrong place; try to move it before any other statement